# What's different about 'const' keyword placement in Dart?

Tags: dart, constants

```
void main() {
  var list1 = const [1, 2, 3];
  const list2 = [1, 2, 3];
}
```

Is there any difference between list1 and list2?

What's different about 'const' keyword placement in Dart?

- between 'const' before the list literal and 'const' before the variable name

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `const` as keyword makes your object `constant` where you are not able to reassign any value to it later.

> Const means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile-time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable.

In your example

```dart
list1 = []; // perfectly fine
list2 = []; // but this throw errors (Error: Can't assign to the const variable 'list2'.)
```

On the other hand, `var` allows you to reassign value to the variable.

However, the `const` after the value makes the value `unmodifiable` let's take a look at an example

```dart
list1.add(22); // ERROR! Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
// but you still can reassign the value 
list1 = [];
// while the 
list2 = []; // throw errors as I said above!
```

the `const` for the value in `const` keyword variable is hidden.

```dart
const list2 = const [1,2,3];
list2.add(22); // ERROR! Cannot add to an unmodifiable list
```

In Short: One makes the memory allocated immutable, the other one the same, and also the pointer pointing to it. in both cases, the list(object) will be immutable.

I hope this helps you understand the difference.

Read more from offical documentation on [dart.dev/language-tour#final-and-const](https://dart.dev/language-tour#final-and-const)